# New Manjaro install, network unavailable, no carrier

Tags: networking, pi-4, ethernet

I am working on a project using an RTL-SDR that I have running well on an x86-64 system under Manjaro that I'm trying to run on a Pi 4B, initially under Raspberry Pi OS (bookworm). While the code runs, it produces somewhat different results. I don't see anything in my code unusual enough to cause it, and I've noticed the driver and API for the RTL-SDR come from different sources, so I thought I'd give Manjaro on Pi a try. My other option is to build the sources use for Manjaro on the Raspberry Pi OS, and I may end up doing that next.

My problem is that I haven't been able to bring the network up using Manjaro. It is fine on Raspberry Pi OS. I can shut that down and boot up Manjaro and no network, ad infinitum. I've tried changing network cables, Raspberry Pi 4B boards, and tried both minimal and kde versions of Manjaro. I'm using the Raspberry Pi installer with the custom option.

I updated the eeprom just in case. It didn't make any difference.

`ip a` shows `lo` up, and no carrier on `wlan0` and `end0`. I started `dhcpcd` and it tells me the same thing - carrier is down. I'm out of ideas and so is Google.

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Linux has used many different network managers and different OS have their preferred/default.

Raspberry Pi OS has (since late 2015) used dhcpcd as default but this changed with Bookworm which switched to NetworkManager (default for Ubuntu and many Debian based OS). It should still be possible to switch to dhcpcd if you prefer and you can install most of the popular network managers.

I haven't used Manjaro in ages so do not know what it uses. Your first task should be to determine what network manager it uses and how to configure it. Alternatively you could install a different network manager commonly used on a Pi.

To further complicate the issue most modern Linux DO NOT use wlan0 or eth0 as is common for Pi. ls /sys/class/net will show which network devices are detected.

Comment: Thanks. I read after posting that dhcpcd isn't required so I have disabled it, although I wonder why it was present in the install image in the first place. ls /sys/class/net shows the same 3 devices I mentioned in the OP. I started the NetworkManager service but it still doesn't bring the network up, and `ip a` still gives 'no carrier' on both wlan0 and end0.